# Some info pages missing

Tags: ubuntu, info

On my computer (ubuntu 12.04), some **`info`** pages are missing, like for `tar`.
When I enter `info tar`, it opens the **tar manpage** instead of the **tar info manual.**

So how can I install these pages on my system?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On `Debian` and its derivatives like Ubuntu, the `info` pages are not installed unless you install the corresponding `package-doc` package for a given `package`.

So in your case:

```
apt-get install tar-doc
```

A notable exception (though that may only apply to Debian and not Ubuntu) is `bash-doc`. The textinfo bash documentation is not considered as free software by Debian as you're not free to modify it (you have to notify the `bash` maintainers if you want to distribute a modified version of it which is against the Debian policy).

There's a similar case for `texinfo-doc` though in that case there *is* a `texinfo-doc-nonfree` package.

Comment: What can I do if I need bash-doc? How can I install the bash info manual?

Comment: @Bill, you can get it from http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/

Comment: Actually, `bash-doc` is free (but does not contain the bash info manual in wheezy), while `tar-doc` in wheezy does contain the info manual and is non-free. Per https://bugs.debian.org/427804, the info manual is back in the bash-doc package, at least           ./usr/share/info/bash.info.gz, which appears to be the "Bash Reference Manual".

Comment: Not installing the manuals is just a really sad default.

Answer (score 5):

On my Ubuntu 12.04 system when I run the command `info tar` I actually get the man page for `tar`. You can see what file `info` is using with the `-w` switch.

```
$ info -w tar
*manpages*

$ info -w ls
/usr/share/info/coreutils.info.gz
```

If you search the repos you'll find this:

```
$ apt-cache search info|grep tar
...
pax - Portable Archive Interchange (cpio, pax, tar)
tar-doc - documentation for the tar package
...
```

Install the `tar-doc` package for the info.

There might be an easier way to do this (not that up on `apt..`) but you can find all the missing `info` doc files with this command:

```
$ apt-cache search info | grep -- '-doc '
```

Comment: Yes, it does open the manpages. That is what I said in the question.

Comment: @Kartik - I know I was showing you why.